# How do i save the UserConrol's current Controls and texts to load everything back again into a panel After disposing the original UC?

Tags: c#, winforms, user-controls

Basically i have got a userControl called ctables which is initialized as bellow :

```
    UserControl _ct_save_current_state = new ctables();
    UserControl uc_controller = null;

    private void Menu_Clicks_Handler(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {


        Control clicked = sender as Control;
        string MainMenuItemName = "pMenu" + clicked.Tag.ToString();
        if (sets.clickedMenuItemTag != clicked.Tag.ToString())
        {
            string OldMenuItemName = "pMenu" + sets.clickedMenuItemTag;
            menu_Container.Controls[OldMenuItemName].BringToFront();
            menu_Container.Controls[MainMenuItemName].SendToBack();

            uc_controller.Dispose();
            uc_controller = null;



            switch (MainMenuItemName)
            {
                case "pMenu1": // if the user clicked processes menuItem
                    uc_controller = new processes(); // init uc_controller with processes userControl
                    break;                           // initializing it with a new since im disposing it after . 

                case "pMenu2":                              // now my problem is here .. i dont want this userControl to be disposed .
                    uc_controller = _ct_save_current_state; // more like save it with it's controls and texts 
                    break;                                  //to affect it to uc_controller  when the ctables menu is clicked .

                case "pMenu3":
                    uc_controller = new bots();
                    break;

                default:
                    break;
            }

            op_container.Controls.Add(uc_controller); // adding the new uc_controller to my panel
            uc_controller.Dock = DockStyle.Fill; // fill the panel
            sets.clickedMenuItemTag = clicked.Tag.ToString(); // dont mind this .
        }


    }
```

As i said in the comments , my problem is that i don't know exactly how i can keep the ctables 
UserControl **_ct_save_current_state**  with it's current Controls .. objects etc .. 
And so when uc_controller is disposed  i can re-load it from **_ct_save_current_state** ..

However i kind of feel that  my problem is  because of referencing .. not sure but maybe 
when i did **uc_controller = _ct_save_current_state;** that means if i dispose uc_controller  .. _ct_save_current_state will also gets disposed  maybe ?

need some help , Thanks .

Comment: Add a condition: `if (uc_controller != _ct_save_current_state) { uc_controller?.Dispose(); }`. Btw, your layout might improve using a TabControl (without header) to switch the panels. So you could get rid of all those check menu/select thing/compare tags stuff. Setting `uc_controller = null;` is not required.

Comment: @Jimi thanks for the answer ,
uc_controller? what does the question mark means here ? if its not null then dispose ?
Also i found out that Disposing uc_controller also disposes _ct_save_current_state ... i was right about  the refrencing thing .

I know about TabControl , but i had to challenge myself to something diffrent than usual .

Comment: Not a questions mark, it's a Null-conditional operator (also referred to as the Elvis operator). This: `uc_controller?.Dispose();` means: *if uc_controller is null return null, otherwise execute what's next*; in this case, call `Dispose()`. You don't return anything here, you simply avoid calling `Dispose()` (which would generate an exception) when `uc_controller` is null. -- Yes, when you assign a reference to another reference, both references now point to the same object: if you call `Dispose()`, you dispose of the object these references are pointing to.